# Can I integrate a Discord channel with GitHub pull requests?

Tags: github, discord

I have a programming team that shares code using GitHub, but primarily communicates through Discord. How can I setup my team's Discord to automatically include updates about GitHub commits and pull requests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Integrating GitHub updates into a Discord channel can be done with webhook updates.

[Via Discord - Intro to Webhooks](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)

> 1. Get the webhook URL for the server/channel you want to receive messages:
>
> [image: Getting webhook for #gitupdates]
>
> 2. Open the webhook settings in your GitHub repository settings (**Settings > Webhooks**)
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Click the "Add webhook" button, and enter the Discord-generated
>      URL in the "Payload URL" section.
> 4. **To ensure the webhook displays messages properly, make sure to append '/github' at the end of your URL.**
> 5. For **content type**, stick with application/json, then customize which kind of events trigger webhook messages.
>
> [image: Customizing webhook notifications]
>
> 6. Click the last "Add webhook" button beneath the event notifications
>      customization option, and you're all set!
>
> [image: Github notifications via webhook in Discord]

Answer (score -2):

I would like to add that as of now, Discord web hooks can receive Slack notifications.  Simply add `/slack` to the web hook URL.  This greatly increases the number of apps Discord can receive notifications from.

Comment: How do Slack notifications help set up GitHub notifications?